# How to add a jQuizzy?

Tags: javascript

I've been searching and trying for two days to add the [jQuizzy](http://codecanyon.net/item/jquizzy-premium-quiz-engine/242295) engine to my site with no luck!
I've successfully added some jQuery plugins to my site, but I can't seem to be add this one?!

I created a block. In the block is a link that calls a menu item. The menu item gets a drupal form. In the form I added all the JS and CSS ... Nothing is happening?!

Help!!!

Comment: why drupal form? why you don't create a simple page?

Answer (score 1):

Are you retrieving that form via AJAX ? Then you get the HTML, but in your page is not present the JavaScript/CSS files. You need to add them before, so they are ALREADY present in whatever page the block is placed.